# Nginx - block access to subfolder

Tags: nginx

This is a Next.js with React site. Run with NPM and Nginx proxies to the localhost.

I have the following nginx server block in the virtualhost:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name dev.sekretyrozwojuosobistego.pl;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
        client_max_body_size 15M;

        location /  {
                proxy_pass    http://localhost:4006;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
```

I want to block access to `/private`

If I add a new location this way there are problems:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name dev.sekretyrozwojuosobistego.pl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sekretyrozwojuosobistego.pl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sekretyrozwojuosobistego.pl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        client_max_body_size 15M;


#       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;


        location /private {
               auth_basic  "Work in progress";
               auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/restricted/.htpasswd;
               proxy_pass    http://localhost:4006;

               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


        location /  {
#               auth_basic  "Work in progress";
#               auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/restricted/.htpasswd;
                proxy_pass    http://localhost:4006;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
```

Good of this solution:

- /private can be accessed only by password

Bad of this solution:
I get such errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
webpack-917a29e0b939a068b2f9.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
_app-9d47fe6f5703c9f8e12f.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
_buildManifest.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
_ssgManifest.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

If I comment out the `/private` location block the 404 errors stop happening.

Am I doing it wrong? How to fix that?

EDIT: I was able to make it work this way:

```
            location /  {
#                   auth_basic  "Work in progress";
#                   auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/restricted/.htpasswd;
                    proxy_pass    http://localhost:4006;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            }
    
    
            location ^~/private {
                    auth_basic  "Work in progress";
                    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/restricted/.htpasswd;
                     proxy_pass    http://localhost:4006;
           }
```

However I am not sure if it should be `^~/private` or else...

What I want to block is:
/private
/private/
/private?
/private?whatever
/private/whatever

Comment: please share the full path from the failed resources /private is required by the application

Comment: I just added an EDIT to the original question

Answer (score 0):

it blocks all requests starting with "private"

```
location ~ ^/private {
        deny all;
    }
```

This only accepts requests from the IP addresses you specify.

```
location ~ ^/private {
        allow 192.168.1.100;
        allow 192.168.1.101;
        deny all;
    }
```